# Proof that in the set of natural numbers if $d + e = a + b + c$ then $d^2 + e^2 \geq a^2 + b^2 + c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I actually need to prove that in the set of natural numbers (excluding $0$) if $A + B + C...I = J + K + L\cdots S$ then $A^2 + B^2 + C^2...I^2 > J^2 + K^2 + L^2...S^2$ (nine terms on the left, ten terms on the right). I can easily prove this for if $C = A + B$ Then $C^2 > A^2 + B^2$ (one term on the left, two terms on the right). However I have been unable to prove it for anything higher than 3 terms total, so I thought a good place to start would be five terms total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false: for example, $4+4 = 6+1+1$, but $16+16 < 36+1+1$.

(In general, because $f(x)=x^2$ is convex, we should expect to get a counter-example if the numbers on the left are "bunched together" while the numbers on the right are "spread out".)